# Post form dates to all controllers without a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a basic form using jquery datepicker:

```
<%= form_for @day do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Beginning Date' %>
  <%= f.datepicker :first_day, :size => 6 %>
  <%= f.label 'End Date' %>
  <%= f.datepicker :second_day, :size => 6 %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And these two parameters, first_day, and second_day need to be posted to pretty much every controller in my application.  I'm using the JIRA rest API as the database for this application, and every controller uses a different query, but I would like the same two dates that are posted here to be used in the query.  Example query:

```
@issues = @jira_client.Issue.jql("resolved >= #{Issue.monday} AND resolved <= #{Issue.sunday} AND project = BTRM and issuetype in ('Dev Sub-task', 'QA Sub-task') AND issue in subtaskIssuesFromQuery('issuetype = Story')")
```

Right now, `#{Issue.monday}` and `#{Issue.sunday}` are built in methods that just grab last week's dates.  I would much rather use input from the user to define these two dates.

Again, these two posted dates need to affect all of my controllers, and need to sustain while navigating between pages, which shouldn't be a huge deal since I'm using turbolinks.

I would prefer this form existed in the application.layout so the user can change the date range at any time.

Thanks.

Comment: before_filter in the application_controller can help you

Comment: Do you have an example of how to post user input to a ruby variable using before_filter in the application_controller?

I understand that it will allow me to use a method in every controller, but I still need to get the user input to a variable without saving it to the database.

Comment: why dont you use session[:user_input]..?